# Javascript: How to make a Control send itself in a method

Tags: javascript, onclick

```
<a href="" id="someId" onclick="SomeMethod(self);"></a>
```

Where SomeMethod could have:

```
function SomeMethod(item)
{
  item.setAttribute('name', item.id);
}
```

Instead of:

```
function SomeMethod(itemId)
{
  var someItem;

  someItem = document.getElementById(itemId);
  someItem .setAttribute('name', someItem .id);

}
```

Silly example, but the idea is not to send in the id itself, but the actual control calling the method.  I swear this can be done but have had no luck searching... partially because I'm not even sure what to search on.

I thought it was self, but self doesn't seem to be what I want when the script I have runs.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the `this` Keyword.

```
<a href="" id="someId" onclick="SomeMethod(this);"></a>
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple.  Kind of felt dirty asking but oh well.

Answer (score 16):

You actually don't need to pass **this** as an argument to your function, because you've got a **click event object** that you can access. So:

```
<a href="" id="someId" onclick="clickEventHandler()"></a>
<script>
function clickEventHandler(event) {

    if (!event) {
        event = window.event; // Older versions of IE use 
                              // a global reference 
                              // and not an argument.
    };

    var el = (event.target || event.srcElement); // DOM uses 'target';
                                                 // older versions of 
                                                 // IE use 'srcElement'
    el.setAttribute('name', el.id);

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

I tend to use this approach in all function calls from HTML attributes:-

```
onclick="SomeMethod.call(this)"
```

Then in the javascript do:-

```
function SomeMethod()
{
   this.setAttribute('name', this.id);
}
```

This has a distinct advantage when you may also assign directly to event handler properties in Javascript code:-

```
document.getElementById("someID").onclick = SomeMethod
```

If SomeMethod took the context element as a parameter it would very awkward to set up:-

```
function(id) {
   var elem = document.getElementById(id)
   elem.onclick = function() { SomeMethod(elem); }
}("someID");
```

Worse yet this would be memory leaking closure.

Comment: Elegant and flexible solution.

Answer (score 2):

At this point: `SomeMethod(this)` - `this` returns window object so do not use it. The right way to use `this` keyword is making it context relevant, so use `SomeMethod.call(this)`.