# Remove self element onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have an element that is added using javascript to my HTML document. I am trying to remove it when I click on that same element. I do not know the id of the element yet, I have just included a sample id for now.

I have already tried looking at this answer here ([Creating an element that can remove it self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650131/creating-an-element-that-can-remove-it-self)) and tried using the method provided here ([Javascript: How to make a Control send itself in a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619514/javascript-how-to-make-a-control-send-itself-in-a-method)) as well to reference the element but have had no luck.

Here is what I have so far.

```js
function remove() {
  var element = this.id;
  //I have also tried using document.getElementByID(this.id)
  element.remove();
  //I have also tried using element.parentNode.removeChild(element); to remove the element.
}
```

```html
<div id="i" onclick="remove(this)">Sample text</div>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but this is the error I keep getting.

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined"

Comment: You are getting `this.id` and trying to remove that. It would be `this.remove()`, which won't work in IE, if you care. Also, you should learn to separate your JavaScript from your HTML.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to pass `this` through the function call in html `onclick` so it could refer to the element then you have to use it as parameter in the function definition, otherwise, if you use `this` in the function definition, it will just refer to the window object.

This will work fine

```js
function remove(el) {
  var element = el;
  element.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="i" onclick="remove(this)">Sample text</div>
```

Comment: Why storing the element in a variable if you just want to remove it

Comment: Because `onclick="this.remove()"` is too mainstream

Answer (score 7):

Minimalist solution:

```html
<div onclick="this.remove()">Sample text</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

your remove function should be like this

```
function remove(elem){
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

your are passing a `this` in your html, which is the html tag itself, however, when you using `this` in your js function, that `this` is the function itself, so you will get error by trying to use the js function's id as element id

Answer (score 2):

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined"

This means the object you're trying to remove doesn't exist what makes complete sense because **this.id** isn't defined anywhere.

To correctly reference a html element using javascript you need to use the **document.getElementById()** function. The id of the html element you're trying to remove is i - so try `document.getElementById("i");`

```js
function remove() {
  var element = document.getElementById("i");
  element.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="i" onclick="remove(this)">Sample text</div>
```

Another - more elegant way - is to pass a reference to the object you clicked on with the callback function. This is simply done by adding **event** as a parameter. Inside the callback you can reference the element using **e.target**.

```js
function remove(e) {
  var element = e.target;
  element.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="i" onclick="remove(event)">Sample text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To match your query, using `outerHTML` will remove the elements and his components from the DOM.

This require to use `document.getElementById()`.

```js
function remove(me) {
  document.getElementById(me).outerHTML = ""
}
```

```html
<div id="i" onclick="remove(this.id)">Sample text</div>
```

A better coding practice, as the post is upvoted:

- Using 3 chars for Id of elements is better
- We can filter elements by type with `target.nodeName`, but the type need to be written in uppercase.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.nodeName, e.target.id)
  if (e.target.nodeName === "DIV"){
    document.getElementById(e.target.id).outerHTML = ""
  }
}, false)
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="el1">Sample text</div>
  <div id="el2">Sample text</div>
  <div id="el3">Sample text</div>
  <div id="el4">Sample text</div>
  <div id="el5">Sample text</div>
  <div id="el6">Sample text</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this in normal JS function you'll need to bind this to function. Else it'll default to window object, this in normal js points to window object. If you want to use this in to point to an object invoking the function then use `()=>{}` arrow functions

```js
function remove(element) {
   console.log(this) //will log Window Object
  //I have also tried using document.getElementByID(this.id)
  element.remove();
  //I have also tried using element.parentNode.removeChild(element); to remove the element.
}
```

```html
<div id="i" onclick="remove(this)">Sample text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first grab your element:

```
const myDiv = document.querySelector('div');
```

then add click event listener to it, so when it gets clicked on, the callback method gets invoked, where 'e.target' acts as 'this', and finally remove it using remove():

```
myDiv.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.target.remove();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use inline event listeners (the one on the button in this example is only for simplification).

```js
function createDiv() {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = `Sample text, created on ${new Date()}`;
  div.addEventListener('click', remove);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

function remove(e) {
  e.target.remove();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="createDiv()">Add a div</button>
```

If you cannot access the element for adding a listener, you can also use a delegate listener:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', remove);

function remove(e) {
  // you need some check here if you don't want any element to be removed on clicking it
  e.target.remove();
}
```

```html
<div>foo</div>

<div>Sample text</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this, so your JavaScript and CSS are cached. Just make sure you change your filenames when updating your files upon deployment *(when people know your site exists)*.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, M, I, S, Q;// for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
function remove(e){
  e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
}
var sample = I('sample');
sample.onclick = function(){
  remove(this);
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#content{
  padding:7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <div id='sample'>Sample Text</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```